# forget password not working in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, passwords, gmail

I tried to click on link forget password and it says email has been sent but I didn't receive email

I am using gmail smpt in db config
I have already tried to change the setting in .env file but still nothing

This is mail config

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=username@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

This isn't working it only says email has been sent but I didn't receive mail
I have also allowed in gmail to use Allow less secure apps: ON
so that app can directly send mail

Comment: have you got config/mail.php 'pretend' value set to true or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the value of `MAIL_DRIVER` from `mail` to `sendmail` in the .env file

```
 MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
 MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
 MAIL_PORT=465
 MAIL_USERNAME=email@gmail.com
 MAIL_PASSWORD=password
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

In account setting of gmail allow unsecured app to send mail works for me

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using `smpt` driver. but in configuration you have set to `mail`.
So, you need to set `MAIL_DRIVER` from `mail` to `smtp` as given below:

'MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`.

Answer (score 0):

Which password you are using ? Is that password which you are using to get login to gmail server ?

If yes then go to Myaccount of gmail then go to sign in and security and go to App password and generate password for Mail App and use that password.

May be that works for you. Same is working for me. Also change the following settings in your .env file.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```